# Postman request with body Form data to json

Tags: json, rest, web-services, postman, form-data

I have a problem with postman...

For one side, I can make this request with the body in form data.
[image]

But, when I try to send the same request with the body in raw(json) I got this:

[image]

I am trying to send the data via Angular 5 to a Drupal 8 Backend.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your backend designed to receive HTTP request with JSON header ? If it only accepts form-data, you have your answer. Can't see wrongness in your pictures

Comment: Yes, thanks @JeanRostan that give me a [clue](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#page-4) The entity-body follows the encoding requirements of the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type.

Comment: your API seems to accept only form-data authentification. If you're the designer of the backend, you can make it accept JSON content too, but you need to handle the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend if the backend can receive a JSON format.

In my case, I am working with the Drupal 8 Module simple Oauth. and the The format for OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens is actually described in a separate spec, [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

More concrete [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#page-4)

> The entity-body follows the encoding requirements of the
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type as defined by HTML
> 4.01 [W3C.REC-html401-19991224].

So, In my particular case, I will try to send a form-data from angular.

Thanks: [Jean Rostan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9571900/jean-rostan)

Comment: were you able to do the request from angular? I have the same problem

Comment: yep, like I answerd, it depends in the backend.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding to the Headers the Content-Type: application/json

[image]

Comment: Done, not result.

Comment: By selecting `JSON (application/json)` from that dropdown - it would have set the header automagically anyway.

Comment: There are APIs that require to explicitly send the Content-Type in the Headers too. For example, the Zendesk API.

Comment: Yep I get that, I was just making you aware that by selecting that option in Postman, will also add the header with that content-type to the request. So you don't 'have' to manually set it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the backend may not accept JSON if you are viewing this question.  I was having the exact same issue but with a different front end.  For an example that worked for me to just get a starting response, you might use:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const querystring = require("querystring");

const authenticate = async () => {

.post((req, res) => {
  let authData = {
    grant_type: "password",
    client_id: "id",
    client_secret: "secret",
    username: "name",
    password: "password"
  };

  const authResponse = await axios.post(
    "http://blah.com/endpoint",
    querystring.stringify(authData)
  );

  return res.send(authResponse.data);
}

authenticate()
```

This is in a async/await format that excludes a couple setup steps that you may need including try/catch, but you should be able to take the above and attempt to convert it to your needs and get the needed result.