# Django Rest-framework: Unable to create a user with profile picture

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-3.0

I am writing a create user API by extending the class `users` with `AbstractBaseUser` class. The API was working fine for regular `model fields` like `EmailField`, `CharField`, `BooleanField`. But then I decided to store the `profile_picture` of users as well. So I create a new field `profile_picture` as `ImageField` to store the path of user's profile picture in the same extended `users` model.

**models.py**

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    """
    This model is used to store user login credential and profile information.
    It's a custome user model but used for Django's default authentication.
    """

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', max_length=None, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # defing a custome user manager class for the custome user model.
    objects = managers.UserManager()

    # using email a unique identity for the user and it will also allow user to use email while logging in.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Then I updated  `UserAPIView` class to add `parser_classes = (FileUploadParser)`

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework import status
from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser



class UserAPIViews(APIView):
    """
    """

    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        """
        print(request.data)
        serialized_data = serializers.UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():

            try:
                user_id = serialized_data.save()
            except IntegrityError as error:
                message = f"Email already exist."
                return Response ({
                    'error_message' : message,
                    'status' : status.HTTP_226_IM_USED
                })

            subject = 'Eitan - Case Manager Account Credentials'
            body = f"Hi {serialized_data.validated_data.get('first_name')} Your case manager account is ready. Please use following credentials to login. Email - {serialized_data.validated_data.get('email')}, Password - {serialized_data.validated_data.get('password')} Thank You! Team Eitan."
            sender = "steinnlabs@gmail.com"
            to = serialized_data.validated_data.get('email')

            send_mail(subject, body, sender, [to], fail_silently=False)

            success_message = f"User has been created."

            return Response({
                'success_message' : success_message,
                'status' : status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            })

        else:
            return Response (serialized_data.error_messages)
```

Updated `settings.py` to add `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`

**settings.py**

```
# Image upload configurations
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

Now, when I pass the object to the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/` it returns -

```
{
    "detail": "Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."
}
```

**JSON object**

```
{
    "first_name": "Abhishek",
    "last_name": "Muley",
    "email": "yogesh@steinnlabs.com",
    "password": "1234",
    "profile_picture":"Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/sample_image.png"
}
```

Comment: If you are uploading a file, you should use formdata instead of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending data json object, send data as form object, if you choose to send the data as form object, then you need to mention parser_classes = [FileUploadParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser]

Following is the link to help to define form data.
[Postman request with body Form data to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676489/postman-request-with-body-form-data-to-json)

```
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        def create(self, validated_data):
            request = self.context.get('request')
            user_obj = user.User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

```
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = user.User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = user_details_serializer.UserSerializer
        # permission_classes = (AdminAccessPermission,)
        filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter]
        parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
        search_fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'status']
        ordering_fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'status']
```

Comment: updated parser classes in views and it has started working `parser_classes = [FileUploadParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser]`